# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (demo project)

Tags: javascript, react-native, stack

This is App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, ImageBackground, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

import StartGameScreen from "./screens/StartGameScreen";
import GameScreen from "./screens/GameScreen";
import Colors from "./constants/color";

export default function App() {
  const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState(null);

  function pickedNumberHandler(pickedNumber) {
    setUserNumber(pickedNumber);
  }

  let screen = <StartGameScreen onPickNumber ={pickedNumberHandler}/>; //StartGameScreen에서 confirm 버튼으로 선택된 숫자를 물려받기
  
  if (userNumber) {
    screen = <GameScreen userNumber ={userNumber} />;
  }

  return (
    <LinearGradient colors={[Colors.primary700 , Colors.accent500]} style={styles.rootScreen}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/images/background.png")}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={styles.rootScreen}
        imageStyle={styles.backgroundImage}
      >
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.rootScreen}> 
          {screen} 
        </SafeAreaView> 
      </ImageBackground>
    </LinearGradient>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rootScreen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    opacity: 0.15,
  },
});
```

This is GameScreen.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import Title from "../components/ui/Title";
import NumberContainer from "../components/game/NumberContainer";
import PrimaryButton from "../components/ui/PrimaryButton";

function generateRandomBetween(min, max, exclude) {
  const rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

  if (rndNum === exclude) {
    return generateRandomBetween(min, max, exclude);
  } else {
    return rndNum;
  }
}

let minBoundary = 1;
let maxBoundary = 100;

function GameScreen({ userNumber }) {
  const initialGuess = generateRandomBetween(
    minBoundary,
    maxBoundary,
    userNumber
  );
  const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState(initialGuess);

  function nextGuessHandler(direction) {
    if (direction === "lower") {
      maxBoundary = currentGuess; 
    } else {
      minBoundary = currentGuess + 1;
    }
    const newRndNumber = generateRandomBetween(
      minBoundary,
      maxBoundary,
      currentGuess 
    );
    setCurrentGuess(newRndNumber);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.Container}>
      <Title> Opponent's Guess </Title>
      <NumberContainer>{currentGuess} </NumberContainer>
      <View>
        <Text> Higher or lower? </Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          <PrimaryButton onPress={nextGuessHandler.bind(this, "lower")}>
            -
          </PrimaryButton>
          <PrimaryButton onPress={nextGuessHandler(this, "greater")}>  
            +
          </PrimaryButton>
        </View>
      </View>
      {/* <View>LOG ROUNDS</View> */}
    </View>
  );
}

export default GameScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
});
```

It is a situation where you enter a number in the Start GameScreen component, press the confirm button, move on to the GameScreen component, and receive a random number.
However, the following error occurs when receiving random numbers.
The problem is likely to occur in the recursive function of GameScreen, but I can't see any errors, so I want help

Comment: You said, "The following error occurs when receiving random numbers." But there's no error description after that sentence. Note that your `generateRandomBetween` function is recursive and also a potential source of a stack overflow. You need to spend some time with your debugger. If you don't know how to use it, now is a perfect time to learn.